# Confirmation Email for publishing pdf

Tags: php, node.js, html-email, email-confirmation, webapi

I have a question about developing a webapi. I want to send someone an email with an confirmation Link and If he clicks on it he should be redirected to a thanks page and get a second email with a pdf.

Unfortunatly I have no idea how to create the confirmation link. I can use every web language as php and node js.

Comment: There is a lot of stuff out on the web, believe me. Just search for what you ask and you'll find something, I am sure of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to generate a long and random id and then pass that id as a url parameter.

```
var key = '25f56c64ee724e15b1b83688e9785a38'; /* Generated Key. */
var link = `https://some-url.com/example/${key}`;
```

In your database you would have a lookup table that maps the key to the userId.

The route for /example/{key} would then perform a fetch of the user information and generate the page and could also send the email with the pdf.

**Note** that the security here is is based on the randomness and length of your key. Adding an expiration would be good practice.